# How to check that all the files uploaded by Picasso lib?

Tags: android, picasso

I want before render MainActivity check what all pictures is loaded:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ...
    getBitmapsByURLs(urls);
}

public void getBitmapsByURLs(List<String> urls) {
    final List<Target> targets = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < urls.size(); i++) {
        final int k = i;
        Target target = new Target() {

            @Override
            public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
                Log.i("TEMP", "Loaded: " + k);
                targets.remove(this);
            }

            @Override
            public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {
                targets.remove(this);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {
                Log.i("TEMP", "Preparing: " + k);
            }
        };
        targets.add(target);
        Picasso.with(this)
                .load(urls.get(i))
                .memoryPolicy(NO_CACHE, NO_STORE)
                .into(target);
    }
}
```

How I can check inside onCreate what all pictures is loaded?
If I write `while` on method onCreate (after call getBitmapsByURLs) then it will be called before all pictures are loaded.

Comment: I'm try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33518703/picasso-first-run-not-call-onbitmaploaded-in-for-loop#comment65424167_33520908 but not success

Answer (score 0):

You must be known that when you use

```
Picasso.with(this)
            .load(urls.get(i))
            .memoryPolicy(NO_CACHE, NO_STORE)
            .into(target);
```

to load a picture,it is a **asynchronized** task.First picasso download the picture from internet.After downloading is finished,the picture will be loaded into target.Of course,when downloading,the main thread will never be waiting.Picasso use something like `Observer-Subcriber` or interface `Future` to make the main thread informed that downing is over.Above all,no matter what you write after `getBitmapsByURLs(urls)`,it will be called before picasso finishes loading pictures.(Because it usually costs some more time to download pictures and load them into targets).
What's more.This is not a recommended way to do such a time-costing work in `onCreate()`.Because `onCreate()` is called in main thread.If you do something costs much time here,then you will get an **Application Not Responding** error.