# Picasso Targets onBitmapLoaded not called in for loop

Tags: android, picasso

Below code snippet for load file into Bitmap and save this file in internal directory(i.e PNG,or JPG format)

```
final List<Target> targets = new ArrayList<Target>();
final List<Target> targetsNormal = new ArrayList<Target>();
for (int j = 0; j < defaultTileImage.size(); j++) {

    final String slangTiles = defaultTileImage.get(j).getPairName() +
            ApplicationConstants.SLANG_TILES;
    final String normalTiles = defaultTileImage.get(j).getPairName() +
            ApplicationConstants.NORMAL_TILES;

    final int k = j;

    Target target = new Target() {
        @Override
        public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
            Log.i("Targets", "Loaded: " + k);
            targets.remove(this);
            saveIntoBitmap(bitmap, slangTiles);
        }
        @Override
        public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {
            targets.remove(this);
        }
        @Override
        public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {
            Log.i("Targets", "Preparing: " + k);
        }
    };


    Target targetNormal = new Target() {
        @Override
        public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
            Log.i("TargetsNormal", "Loaded: " + k);
            targetsNormal.remove(this);
            saveIntoBitmapSlang(bitmap, normalTiles);
        }
        @Override
        public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {
            targetsNormal.remove(this);
        }
        @Override
        public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {
            Log.i("TargetsNormal", "Preparing: " + k);
        }
    };
    targetsNormal.add(targetNormal);
    Picasso.with(MainActivity.this)
            .load(defaultTileImage.get(j).getNormalTileImg()) // Start loading the current target
            .resize(100, 100)
            .into(targetNormal);

    targets.add(target);
    Picasso.with(MainActivity.this)
            .load(defaultTileImage.get(j).getSlangTileImg()) // Start loading the current target
            .resize(100, 100)
            .into(target);
}
```

Also visited this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33520908/1339473) and implemented as per this guideline that make Target a strong reference . But unfortunately many time **onBitmapLoaded** not get any callback.

*I truly appreciate your help in resolving the proble*m

Comment: dude can you post the screenshots for both the cases and image url ? (suggestion use [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide))

Comment: screenshot ? Actually i am just doing operation like save this file.

Comment: [Enable logging](https://github.com/square/picasso/blob/master/picasso/src/main/java/com/squareup/picasso/Picasso.java#L447) in Picasso, and analyse it.

Comment: canceled     [R11]+19s target got garbage collected. @R.Zagórski
It may issue on creating a strong reference ?

Comment: Make sure targets and targetsNormal are global variables instead of local.

Comment: @DanielZolnai and @ R. Zagórski targets and targetsNormal  made a global variable that solved issue.
You can post this comment as answer i will surely accept it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make sure `targets` and `targetsNormal` are global variables instead of local.

If they are local variables, they can be garbage collected as soon as the method has been left.