# How to download image and store image in internal memory in asynctask onPost method using Picasso

Tags: android, bitmap, android-asynctask, picasso

I'm trying to download image from url and store that image to internal memory.I'm using picasso library(version:'2.5.0').But onBitmapLoaded() is not calling first time.i saw this link [Picasso first run not call onBitmapLoaded in for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33518703/picasso-first-run-not-call-onbitmaploaded-in-for-loop). But it is not working for me.Please help me

```
final List<Target> targets = new ArrayList<Target>();
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String sResult) {
   for (int i = 0; i < arraylist.length(); i++) {
         DownloadImage(arraylist.get(i));
    }
}

 public void DownloadImage(String ImageUrl){
     final String imageDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Images/";
    sPath = "";
    Target target = new Target() {
        @Override
        public void onBitmapLoaded(final Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {

            FileOutputStream fos = null;
            try {
                File myDir = new File(imageDir);
                if (!myDir.exists()) {
                    myDir.mkdirs();
                }
                myDir = new File(myDir, fileName);
                fos = new FileOutputStream(myDir);

                sPath = myDir.getAbsolutePath();
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
                mStudent.setPhoto(sPath);
                mStudentDB.addOrUpdateStudent(mStudent);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    fos.flush();
                    fos.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            targets.remove(this);

        }

        @Override
        public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {
            targets.remove(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {
        }
    };
    Picasso.with(activity)
            .load(ImageUrl)
            .into(target);
 }
```

Comment: Dont write images in `onPost` instead write it in `onBackground`

Comment: Do you want to download image to show offline or do you want to make image visible in gallery ?

Comment: @ Sohail Zahid  in my case i'm getting image url from server.so onPost method i want to download image

Comment: @  Burhanuddin Rashid   i want to show list of user name with image in activity.so while login i'm getting all data and store in sqlite db and next screen i want to show user list

Comment: `server.so onPost method i want to download image`. There is no onPost method. Please correct the subject. And you have an arraylist full of urls so you try to download more images at once. And you save all with the same fileName.